# Assigning data from a JSON response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have the following assignment of a JavaScript object inside a `script` tag.

```
<script>
  searchdata = {"employees":[{"name":"john doe","sal": "10000"}]};
</script>
```

i am using `searchdata` in various places, like so:

```
function viewemp(){
  var emp =  searchdata.employees;
}

function viewemp1(){
  var emp1 =  searchdata.employees;
}

function viewemp2(){
  var emp2 =  searchdata.employees;
}
```

That's all working without any issues.

What I am looking at is, I would like to set (assign) `searchdata` from a jquery ajax call data, i.e., I want to assign data from the jquery ajax response.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var searchdata = new Object();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/GlobalData.asmx/FindEmpList",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    searchdata  = eval(data.d);
                }
           });
        });
 </script>
```

but when i look html "page view source" page, `searchdata` is showing empty.  It's not assigned any jquery ajax data. I want to see what data jquery returned in html "Page view Source" page.
Can any one help me how to see my jquery returend data in "Page view source"

I can see my json data in console log too.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, it's dangerous and unreliable. Why not use `.clone`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the data through View > Source, it isn't part of the source. It is data added to the JavaScript environment separately.

Comment: even i can able see google.com View-> source i am able to see some json data too

Comment: Then that is data that is in the page source and not data that is fetched with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable so, this variable is local, in `function () {` context

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var searchdata = new Object(); // <-- LOCAL
   ...
});
```

try this:

public variable:

```
 window.searchdata = (function() {

     var sdata = {};
     return {
        set: function(data){
           sdata = data;
        },
        get: function() {
           return sdata;
        },
        employees: function() {
           return sdata.employees;
        } 
     };

 }());
```

AJAX:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/GlobalData.asmx/FindEmpList",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                searchdata.set(eval(data.d));
            }
       });
});
```

Functions to get searchdata values:

```
function viewemp(){
  var emp =  searchdata.get().employees;
}

function viewemp1(){
  var emp1 =  searchdata.employees();
}

function viewemp2(){
  var emp2 =  searchdata.get().employees;
}
```

`searchdata.get().employees` and `searchdata.employees()` return the same value, but you have more options for how to return the values.

maybe it's more than you need, but can help you understand how to work with this type of variables and contexts